# Undefined Method Error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in rails and i could use a little help.
I have the following setup in rails

```
Day has_many Bookings
Booking belongs_to Day
```

The Booking form in shared/_booking_form is as follows:

```
   <%= form_for Booking.new do |t| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: t.object %>
<div class="field">
  <%= t.label :start %><br>
  <%= t.time_select :start %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= t.label :end %><br>
  <%= t.time_select :end %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= t.label :comentariu %><br>
  <%= t.text_area :comentariu, placeholder: "Adauga un comentariu.."  %>
</div>
<%= t.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The bookings controller look like this

```
  def show
    @bookings = Booking.all
  end
  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
  end
  def create
    @booking = @day.bookings.build(booking_params)
    @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "Book created!"
      redirect_to root_url
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:start, :end, :comentariu)
  end
```

I get this error and i haven't been able to solve

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `bookings' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your `create` action, you have `@day.bookings...`. Your error is indicating that `@day` is nil. Where is it being defined?

Comment: oh, thanks i didn't defined it:). Now it works